# Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient Creates long and fragile `state` GET parameters

Tags: php, openid-connect

I'm looking to make a OICD-enabled site with PHP. I found `Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient`, which seems to work great. However, it seems that when returning to the website from oidc, it creates several very long `state` and `session_state` GET parameters. These params are obviously required, but end up being rather fragile; using `back` navigation breaks things. GET parameters really clutter up the URL as well, and have additionally seen that pre-existing GET parameters are squashed and removed by the auth process.

I'm simply calling the `$oidc->authenticate()` function towards the beginning of my code, nothing else really fancy.

Is there a way to store these state values as session values or cookies, like in other implementations I have seen?

Update:: Found the following config that seems to avoid having the GET parameters, but still nukes any existing GET parameters passed to the page

```
self::$oidc->addScope(array('openid'));
self::$oidc->setAllowImplicitFlow(true);
self::$oidc->addAuthParam(array('response_mode' => 'form_post'));
```

It seems to make the auth flow occur at each page load, which seems pretty heavy as well. Any ideas?